# Remove a tag from inside a function called by .each

Tags: jquery

Inside a function valled by `.each` I want to remove the `a` tag(s)/.
Here is a non-working example:

```
$('div.link').has('div.entry:has(p.title:has(a[href^="http://i.imgur.com/"]))').each(function (i) {
    $(this).css('border', '5px solid');
    $(this).remove('a'); // Does NOT work! Nothing happens...
    console.log($(this));
})
```

Click image below for full size. The marked line is pure coincidence and indicates nothing. To test stuff out, visit http://reddit.com and use Firebug (jQuery is loaded):
[image: Firebug screenshot containing part of Reddits DOM]

Comment: Have you tried `$(this).find('a').remove()`?

Comment: Can you try this instead ? $(this).find('a').remove();

Comment: @Jack: No I hadn't, i'm green to jQuery and haven't really understood its concepts yet.

Comment: @ryadavilli: No I hadn't, i'm green to jQuery and haven't really understood its concepts yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Provide `this` as the context:

```
$("a", this).remove();
```

The second parameter to the `$` function is often times the `context` for your selector, meaning the area in which you'd like to find matches to your selector. In this particular case, we're saying we'd like to find `a` elements within `this`.

jQuery will internally convert this to a find call:

```
$(this).find("a").remove();
```

So if you don't mind a slightly more verbose solution (a few chars, no big deal), you can pick up a very negligible performance boost by cutting out the middle-man syntax and using `.find` directly.

Answer (score 5):

You need to find it, and then remove it:

```
$(this).find('a').remove();
```